Algebra qualifying exam problem about finite fields
I came across an algebra qualifying exam problem that looks very easy to me. I will be really thankful if someone could check whether my solution is correct.
Problem: Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{2^{24}}^{\times}$ be an element of multiplicative order $2^{24} - 1$. How many roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_{4}$ are there in the field $\mathbb{F}_{2^{24}}$.
My Solution: Let $p(x) = x^{2^{24}} - x$ and let $q(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$. First note that $\mathbb{F}_4(\alpha) = \mathbb{F}_{2^{24}}$ as $\alpha$ is a generator of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_{2^{24}}^{\times}$. Because $[\mathbb{F}_4(\alpha) : \mathbb{F}_4] = [\mathbb{F}_{2^{24}} : \mathbb{F}_{4}] = 12$, we find that $\deg q(x) = 12$. Since $p(\alpha) = 0$, it follows by the definition of $q(x)$ that $q(x) \, | \, p(x)$. Finally, $p(x)$ splits completely in $\mathbb{F}_{2^{24}}$ and all of its roots occur with multiplicity $1$ which implies that $q(x)$ also splits completely in $\mathbb{F}_{2^{24}}$ and all of its roots occur with multiplicity $1$. Thus the answer is $\mathbf{12}$.

This is correct. The fact that all roots have multiplicity $1$ simply follows from the well known fact that finite fields are perfect. By the way, I hope you know why $\mathbb{F_4}$ is indeed a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{2^{24}}$.

I wonder why this question was downvoted.

Yes, because $2$ divides $24$.

Please note that posts that simply present a proof and ask if it is correct are off-topic as lacking focus. You are essentially asking multiple questions, a "and is this right?" after every step. To be on topic, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
